# How to return the correct data in a map() function in react-native

Tags: arrays, react-native, map-function

When I input data into my Text input, it goes into this array

```
WorkoutItems([...workoutTextItems, workoutText, setsText])
```

I want to get my data individually from each item, so for example, workoutText is the name of a workout, setsText is the amount of sets I want to do for that workout[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57lOG.png)

So this is my code, I want to have 4 text inputs {workout name} {sets} {reps} {weights}, I don't want them to just be bundled together but to be able to pick where I want each item in the array so I can style them, how do I go about doing that as I'm pretty new to coding and this is my first project

[This is what it is doing at the moment, it's just showing all the data and I can't choose where it goes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLkVM.png)

I've tried messing with the arrays and trying to remove the map but I'm pretty new to this so I'm really unsure what to try next

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at the react documentation.

You should use the useState hook like this:

`const [count, setCount]=useState(0)` for example

in your code, you've:
`const[workoutText, setText]= useState()`

I think it's better to do something like this:

`const [workout, setWorkout]=useState() const [sets, setSets]=useState() const [reps, setReps]=useState() const [weight, setWeight]=useState()`

maybe your options on the bottom of the screen should be a bottom tab navigator, take a look at this documentation:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator

I hope this helps you.